# sequence of closed subspaces is not strictly increasing

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let H be an infinite dimensional hilbert space and $A_{n}$ a sequence of closed subspaces. Prove the sequence is not strictly increasing. I suppose it's sort of intuitive but what is a formal proof?

Comment: Without knowing what the sequence of spaces and what order you are using it is impossible to answer this. For example, if the order is set inclusion and you consider $A_n = \operatorname{sp}\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ then this is a strictly increasing sequence of closed subspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true!

If $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, then it has an infinite orthonormal basis, 
$e_i,i\in \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal.

Set $E_\beta$ to be the closure of the linear span of $\{e_i: i\in \beta\}$, where $\beta\le\alpha$.

Then 
$$
E_0 < E_1 < E_2 <\cdots < E_{\beta_1}< E_{\beta_2},
$$
for all the ordinals is $\alpha$.